# VBA to refresh all sheets in a workbook excluding only one Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

[Sample Heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Coj.jpg) Hello I have pivot tables in 6 sheets of my workbook out of 9 and one sheet (Sorted) has columns arranged in a particular order but it doesn't have pivot tables. I want to refresh sheets with Pivot only. I have used the below VBA but it rearranges the columns in the Sorted worksheet. Below is the code

```
Sub RefreshAllPivotTables()
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
            PT.RefreshTable
        Next PT
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: what **exactly** do you mean by *'refresh'*? query tables? calculation? pivot caches?

Comment: All the data in the pivot table should be refrreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible way to exclude one sheet:

```
Sub RefreshAllPivotTables()

    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Sorted" Then
            For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
                PT.RefreshTable
            Next PT
        End If
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Again the order is getting changed in this sheet, please check the picture i have uploaded just few seconds ago

Comment: @VenusJain - I do not see any picture.

Comment: Its under Peer review. Is there any option to attach file here?

Comment: could you please check now

Comment: @VenusJain - what do you do in order to change these the order of the columns? The `.RefreshTable` should not have any impact on them (AFAIK)

Comment: I recorded a macro to rearrange the column

Comment: Sub RearrangeColumn()
'
' RearrangeColumn Macro
'
    Sheets("Sorted Data").Select
    Columns("F:G").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("I:J").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("L:N").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub

Comment: is there anything wrong with the above Macro for rearrange?